# How to enforce security of the system before sending notebook to the service?

Tags: security

I have to send notebook to the service to replace the keyboard. I don't to at least make it hard to for the serviceman to snoop through my private stuff. 
How to enforce security of the system disable easy access to the hard drive?

Is the Windows password is enough in the most cases? I can't remove the hard drive as it could result in loss of the warranty.

Comment: There's no reason to be so paranoid. The only way he could see files would be to take the hard drive out ans browse it, and that wouldn't yield any emails or passwords. At most, he could see documents and installed programs.

Answer (score 2):

Turn on bitlocker.  It is Microsoft native encryption tool.

http://www.pcworld.com/article/2308725/a-beginners-guide-to-bitlocker-windows-built-in-encryption-tool.html

Create a non admin account for them to use a give them access to that account.

Comment: They don't need to use the computer, since the keyboard is being replaced. I think he shouldn't be worried at all, but since he is, does this prevent someone from just removing the drive and looking through it?

Comment: @Zacharee1 - Does encrypting the entire drive prevent somebody from removing the drive and looking through it?  Of course it does.  **If a drive isn't encrypted ANYONE CAN TAKE ownership of the data and view it, infact, I guarantee you I could boot to the drive within 5 hours of work.**  I could even duplicate the hdd, boot to that, and you would never know I have a complete bootable copy of your system.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying, and I think the same happened for you with my comment. I was trying to ask if that encrypts the drive, so that copying is pointless.

Comment: @Zacharee1 - You asked this question in your comment.  "Does this prevent someone from just removing the drive and looking through it?" My response to that question was of course it does because the data is encrypted.  If a drive isn't encrypted it is a little more then non-trivial to mount the drive and a little more trivial then that to actually boot into the drive after all the existing windows user's paswords were changed.  I know exactly what you were saying, I read the words, only one way to read them.

Comment: Ok. Sorry. It was just me, then.